# Realistic Usage of Identity and Roles in .Net 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, .net-5

I am fairly new to coding in the .Net environment. I am having trouble finding "real-world" examples on authentication/authorization using Identity. Most examples I come across are primarily textbook examples that use the ASP .Net registration template.

I am trying to find guidance on where to look (yes, I Googled and I get very unrealistic/unusable use cases or "classroom" examples) or how to do this.

I work for a small school and I am trying to build an application (possibly Blazor - just experimenting with various technologies now) that allows both students and employees to login into a portal and view their relevant data. I have an Employee table and a Student table based on POCO classes. When I add identity to the project it creates Users and Roles tables as well.

I would like to have the "Users" table based on the Student and Employee tables - not have a separate users table. I do not want to have a "registration" option either. I would like the option for an Admin (which would fall under an "Employee") to be able to add users, but not use a registration page.

How would I implement Identity and Roles without using all the extras added? I am using .Net 5.0.

Thank you for your time and pelase forgive the English - it's new to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're trying to do.  It IS possible to [Create a Custom AuthenticationStateProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

But unless you have a VERY robust database already, I wouldn't do it.  Getting the default system set up and migrating users will take at most an hour.  Setting up your own custom authorization system is likely to take you MUCH MUCH longer.

***Having different users in different tables is not a good design plan.  They all have names, phone numbers, e-mails and so on-- put them on one table.***

Answer (score 0):

Hi Derrick and welcome to the community! @Bennyboy1973 is correct, in that both your Students and Employees are all "Users", so they should all be stored in the same table. To add to that response a bit, probably the simplest way for you to manage them is by using Roles, so the Students could be in one role and the Employees could be in another. By having a role attached to each, you can then use the roles as a filter in your queries and you could also restrict the access and actions each type will have based on the role they are in.

Regarding having administrators add the users to the database without public access, this can be done as well. Once you get the default identity system up and running, you can scaffold out the whole system so it can be modified, and probably the easiest way to achieve what you are after is to then modify the default registration (signup) page so that it requires the user to be authenticated to reach it, and then implement a confirmation email to activate each new account.

There are a few things with this approach that you need to be aware of as well.

1. Since the admin will be setting up all the other user accounts, you should modify the email confirmation chain to require a password reset at some point. The administrators can have access to the user's information as needed but shouldn't have the user's passwords.
2. Identity Server will store passwords in an encrypted format, and you'll need an initial user in your database. What this means is that you will have to "seed" an initial admin user into the database that you can use to sign in and get started with everything else. You'll have to research how to do this, as it isn't as simple as just accessing the database directly and adding the user and roles because of the encryption. The program you build should be designed to do this for you on either the first run or if you are connecting to a new database, using a username and password that you know. It will then store the user properly that you can use to sign in as Admin, then change the admin password. This makes the whole thing more secure.

This all sounds like a headache, but it's worth it to work through and know how it all fits together. The, as mentioned in other answers, you can migrate existing data into the database.